# Float left not working in div

Tags: html, css

i have the following HMTML/CSS:

```
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">NAME</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">öffnen</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following set of CSS rules is defined:

```
.cart-preview {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body {
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
    float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-header{
    font-family: 'IBMPlexSans-Bold.woff'
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.product {
    display: flex;
}

.product>div {
    width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
    content: ' \25CF';
    font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
  float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
    content: 'x'
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    top: 15%;
    line-height: 14px;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 205px;
    left: 25%;
}

.checkout .taxes{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
}

.checkout .cart-total{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.cart-total .value {
    float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
    content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
    float: left;
}

.taxes .value {
    float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
    float: left;
}
```

JavScript:

```
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

I don't get the content within the div product-details algined in one horizontal line next to the image. I tried using float: left and left:0. Can someone help me to get the content aligned next to the image and all starting letters are in one line horitontally?

I pasted it into a codepen:

https://codepen.io/seppl2202/pen/QVNdXd

Comment: can you combine all the three into a code snippet or fork them up in a jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: added the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzGgqq with the CSS . 
The Css that needs to be modified is

```
.product-quantity-details{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.product-details{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

The inline-flex will align the items to a single line for `.product-details` and the `align-items: center;` should align the contents in the center perfectly, the color and quantity field.

Comment: It aligns the item perfectly, but the wrong way. Sorry if that was not clear, i want all items to start at the same point next to the image and keep the 'three rows', but the start of these rows should have the same 'left position'. Changing the flex-direction does not work

Comment: I have updated the CSS. I hope this is what you are looking for.              .product-details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start
}                                                                                                                                   .product-quantity-details{
     align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
} Updated the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzGgqq

Comment: Thanks a lot, i forgot to update the second div, thats why my changes did not work. Thanks a lot:)